# How i apply transaction in btnClick event

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void btnHiddenCheckIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{/ointments();

                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "starScript", "checkINClick('" + hidPatientName.Value + "');", true);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you committing the transaction?

Comment: in else part where update query starts

Comment: from here strSQL = @"UPDATE APPOINTMENTS 
                            SET STATUS = 'CHECKED IN' WHERE App_ID = '" + hidAppId.Value + @"'";

Comment: @Nikhil to apply Transaction you may need to modify your current class model, data access model.. Since `Master.objSqlDbComm`: seems to be a SqlCommand object and its property [Transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.transaction.aspx) needs to be set to SqlTransaction object and all the Insert,Update,Delete SqlCommands should have same SqlTransaction object in their [.Transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.transaction.aspx) property!

Comment: when i apply transaction it gives me error like this and transaction fails "ExecuteDataset requires command to have transaction when connection assigned to command is in pending local trans"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nikhil,

Declare `SqlTransaction objSqlTransaction;` at the top, but don't initialize it!

Where you are setting `objSqlDbComm` properties like Connection, TimeOut etc... You need to pass SqlTransaction object to set to `SqlCommand.Transaction` property!

Now where you want to start Transaction initialize the object:

```
objSqlTransaction = Master.objSqlDbComm.SqlConnectionObject.BeginTransaction();
```

And when you are finished with inserts and updates, may be at the end of else... write `transaction.Commit();`, if it was not successful exception will be thrown... So add try catch to your code, declare SqlTransaction before starting try and in catch `transaction.RollBack();`

See complete example on MSDN:
[SqlTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.aspx)

**UPDATE:**
That is because you are using same SqlCommand object for ExecuteNonQuery and ExecuteDataSet, you need to use different SqlCommand object when ExecuteDataSet... Because your SqlCommand is a part of transaction!

Comment: and if you use another connection for ExecuteDataSet, other than the one transaction is using then?